# cordova-plugin-speechrecognition works well on adrioid but fails in ios 13.3

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova-plugins, speech-to-text, ionic5

I have created ionic app and used cordova-plugin-speechrecognition for speech to text conversion.
This works well in android mobile and ios emulator but doesn't work on IOS 13.3

```
    initSpeech() {
this.speechRecognition.hasPermission()
  .then((hasPermission: boolean) => {
    console.log(hasPermission)
    if (!hasPermission) {
      this.speechRecognition.requestPermission()
        .then(
          () => console.log('granted'),
          () => console.log('Denied')
        )
    }
  })
  }

 start() {
// Start the recognition process
this.speechRecognition.startListening()
  .subscribe(
    (matches: Array<string>) => { this.voicetext = matches[0]; this.mainForm.controls['comments'].setValue(matches[0]); },
    (onerror) => console.log('error:', onerror)
  )
  }

//stop listening for(ios only)
      stop() {
    this.speechRecognition.stopListening();

  }
```

code specified in the link https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition is what I have used.

For IOS I have also implemented stop listening and added NSMicrophoneUsageDescription permission
NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription permission in info.list of ios .

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It actually works but with delay, so couldn't recognize its being triggered.